# Sample space for experiments

Tags: probability, combinatorics

10 people are living in a village. They form their government using random choice. Every person has an equal probability to be chosen. Consider two random experiments:

1​. The villagers want to select a Village Council that consists of three persons. The researcher is interested in the list of members of one Council.

2​. Every four months villagers select a President. The same person can be President arbitrary number of times. The same person can be a President and a member of Village Council at the same time. The researcher is interested in the list of Presidents during one year.

Find the number of elements in both sample spaces. What is the difference between these experiments?

My approach to the problem is as follows:

In the first experiment, the sample space involves selecting three persons out of 10 people in the village. Also each outcome is equally likely. Thus here ordering does not matter and is not repeated so we can use combinations to find all possible outcomes for the sample space so here the cardinality of the sample space is $C(10,3)=120$.
In the second experiment, the sample space involves selection of president from 10 people across a span of 4 months. Here a person can be elected arbitrary number of times and can be in council at the same time. Here it is repeating and every 4 months the president election is held so in a year 3 times election occur so the number of ways a presidents can elected are 10x10x10=1000 by using rule of product. Thus the cardinality of the sample space is 1000.
In the first experiment, the outcomes are unordered and not repeated while in the second experiment the outcomes can be repeated. The first experiment is selecting a council of 3 members out of 10 villagers at one time while the second experiment is involving selection of president thrice in a year.

Can you please let me know if the above approach is correct for the given problem statement

Comment: Your conclusions all sounds correct to me and I cannot think of anything that needs to be changed in terms of how you word it.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you